# Tableau Desktop Order of Calculation

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

hope someone here can help with this tableau visualization.

I have a table that have orderId, productName, category, customerId, orderDate, and amount

I need to dynamically (orderDate as slide filter for order date range) give top 10 categories that have the highest total of amount over the costly products/categories (the products/categories that have sum(amount)/count(orderId) > $2000)

I have tried different ways but none of them worked so far... any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Read about order of operations in the tableau help, especially about adding a filter to the “context”

Answer (score 0):

Use context filter option here. Please add the filters to context (Right click on filter + Add to context) and then use the top N functionality.